# Ruby on Rails - No method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nomethoderror

I'm completing this airbnb clone course (https://code4startup.com/projects/build-airbnb-with-ruby-on-rails-level-1) but have diverted a bit in order to complete my own project; a marketplace for education camps. Therefore I've added an additional model. It now has User>Listing>Course.

Since adding this course I keep receiving the following error upon running the server and going to localhost:3000/courses/new I've tried searching for the problem on stackoverflow but I'm not experienced enough to describe and therefore find the issue, I'd appreciate any ideas.

**Error Message**

```
undefined method `curriculum_type' for #<Listing:0x007fb776ac0f50>
Extracted source (around line #15):


            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Course Type</label>
              <%= f.select :curriculum_type, [["English Language", "English Language"], ["Culture", "Culture"], ["Sports", "Sports"], ["Tech/Science", "Tech/Science"], ["Adventure", "Adventure"], ["Mixture", "Mixture"]],
                            id: "type", prompt: "Select...", class: "form-control" %>
            </div>
          </div>
```

**Models**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :listings
  has_many :courses, :through => :listings
end

class Listing < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :courses
end

class Course < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :listing
end
```

**Courses Controller**

```
class CoursesController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_course, except: [:index, :new, :create]
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show]

  def index
    @courses = current_user.listings.courses
  end

  def new
    @course = current_user.listings.build
  end

  def create
    @course = listings.build(course_params)
    if @course.save
      redirect_to listing_course_path(@course), notice: "Saved..."
    else
      render :new, notice: "Something went wrong..."
    end
  end

  def show

  def listing
  end

  def pricing
  end

  def description
  end

  def photo_upload
  end

  def amenities
  end

  def location
  end

  def update
    if @course.update(course_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Saved..."
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Something went wrong..."
    end
    redirect_back(fallback_location: request.referer)
  end

  private

  def set_course
    @course = Course.find(params[:id])
  end

  def room_params
    params.require(:course).permit(:name, :course_type, :summary, :address, :course_places, :start_date, :finish_date, :price)
  end

end
end
```

**Courses new.html.erb**

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    Create your course listing
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="devise-container">

      <%= form_for @course do |f| %>
        <div class="row">
          </div>

          <div class="col_md_4 select">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Course Type</label>
              <%= f.select :curriculum_type, [["English Language", "English Language"], ["Culture", "Culture"], ["Sports", "Sports"], ["Tech/Science", "Tech/Science"], ["Adventure", "Adventure"], ["Mixture", "Mixture"]],
                            id: "type", prompt: "Select...", class: "form-control" %>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col_md_4 select">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Places</label>
              <%= f.select :course_places, [["1", 1], ["2", 2], ["3", 3], ["4", 4], ["5", 5], ["6", 6], ["7", 7]],
                            id: "places", prompt: "Select...", class: "form-control" %> -->
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div><%= f.submit "Create My Course", class: "btn btn-primary-green" %></div>
      <% end %>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In Rails Console I can create all models, but it seems that it is not recognising the Courses Model when I start the server

Comment: What's in your schema.rb file? It looks as though you haven't added the `curriculum_type` attribute for listings yet.

Comment: @colincr its in there: 
create_table "courses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "curriculum_type"

Comment: Have you run a migrate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller is building a `Listing` object, but your `curriculum_type` attribute is an attribute for a `Course`. You'll want to modify your controller to be building a `Course` object if that's the case, or add the attribute to `Listing`.

Comment: thank you! so should my New method look like this?
def new
@course = current_user.listings.courses.build
end
?

Comment: That looks correct; does your course save properly?

Comment: this new New method unfortunately doesn't work, new error: "undefined method `courses' for #<Listing::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fc2ccbfcd68>"

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure if it saves correctly, it works in rails console if that's what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Your `Course` saved without rollback and was given an ID by ActiveRecord.

Comment: Does `current_user` actually return a user in your Rails console?

Comment: Not sure if I'm doing it right but when I entered current_user it came back with: "undefined local variable or method 'current_user' for main:Object"

Comment: It depends on how you have your users setup, but `current_user` generally requires a session and isn't accessible in the console unless you explicitly did something like `current_user = User.find(<whatever user id>)`.

Comment: Ah yes, doing it that way does come up with the current_user successfully

Comment: Glad it helped! If this solved your issue please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Yes thank you, I've just got to work out why it still isn't working!

Comment: Make sure you're properly creating your ties between your user, course, and listing one at a time. Good luck; I'll keep an eye out for any additional questions you post.